# sencha touch 2.0 : How to apply conditional background color to list item

Tags: css-selectors, sencha-touch-2

I would like to apply a background-color style conditionally in the itemTpl of a list.
Let's say my itemTpl looks something like:

```
itemTpl: '<tpl if="condition"> <div class="highlight"> ... </div> </tpl> '
```

The problem is that when I do that the style "highlight" doesn't apply to the whole list item.

If I inspect the DOM, I see that the content of my itemTpl is inside another div with class "x-list-item" containing another div with class "x-list-item-label". Therefore, applying a background style to my itemTpl does not fill the full area...

Does anyone know how to affect the whole area (thus the "x-list-item" or "x-list-item-label") ?

Is there a css/sass trick to affect the parent of my div ?
Is there a sencha trick ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for my misunderstood. Then the following will work. I'm sure.

Suppore that you set an id for your element (not component, I know), for eg:

`<span id="something-here">{whatever you want to show}</span>`.

Then:

- `Ext.get('something-here')` returns your element
- `Ext.get('something-here').up('div.x-list-item')` returns the nearest parent of that node which has tag `div` with class `x-list-item`

I've already tested this via `show()` and `hide()` and the element is interacted well.

To add CSS class to an element, simply use `addCls('special-css-class')`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your input. How can I access the x-list-item-label in using Ext.ComponentQuery? And if I can assess it that way, why should I do it inside the XTemplate member function? Is there a way to get a ref to the x-list-item inside this member function ?

Comment: try something like this `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('x-list-item-label[class="highlight"]');`

Comment: this doesn't work as ComponentQuery is not designed to select classes. 'x-list-item' is not an xtype but the class of the div surrounding the itemTpl...

Comment: sorry, let's try `Ext.getCmp('your-xlist-item-label-id').up()` instead (of course you need to create an id for your label. note: `up()` mean goes up one level in DOM tree

Comment: Sorry again, but I cannot use Ext.getCmp since I am not able to put an id on the items. This is the whole problem:I don't know how to acces the items of an xlist. The only id I have is on the xlist itself.

Comment: simply change this `<div class="highlight">` to `<div id="highlight">`, get it through Ext.getCmp(), and get the parent component through `up()`

Comment: It doesn't work, because Ext.getCmp() is made to query components and my div in my template is not a component... Sorry again, I don't want to sound rude...

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm quite sure it will work. Sorry so much for my misunderstood though... :)

Comment: Thanks a ton! Finally you nailed it ;)